# Is it possible to inject a controller or another class in an EmberJS Component?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, dependency-injection

I'm trying to use a method from one controller inside a component but something must be wrong.

I have the route `/calendars` with its own controller (`controllers/calendars.js`) and template (`templates/calendars.hbs`)

Inside `calendars.hbs` I have implemented a chain of components with templates for the main screen of my app and for the menu. Inside the menu, I have the final component that should call to a calendars' controller method.

## Controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions:{
    createCalendar: function(){
      console.log("app/controllers/calendars.js");
    }
  }

});
```

## Route:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin,{
  model: function(params) {
    return [
      {id:"1", name:"Calendario de trabajo", shared:false, position: 0},
      {id:"2", name:"Calendario personal", shared:false, position: 1},
    ];
  },

  actions:{
    createCalendar: function(calendar){
      console.log("app/routes/calendars.js");
    }
  }
});
```

## Component:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  calendars: Ember.inject.controller("calendars");

  actions: {
    createCalendar: function(){
      console.log("app/components/menu/calendar-dock-footer.js");
      this.calendars.createCalendar();
    }
  }
});
```

## Templates:

### calendars.hbs

```
{{#main-template}}
  {{#link-to "calendars.new" (query-params posX=150 posY=50)}} Show me the money! {{/link-to}}
  {{outlet}}
  {{calendars.full-calendar size="calendar" action="createEvent"}}
{{/main-template}}
```

### main-template.hbs (component)

```
...
  {{menu.main-dock}}
...
```

### main-dock.hbs (component)

```
...
{{menu.calendar-dock-footer}} 
...
```

### calendar-dock-footer.hbs (component with button)

```
<div class="row ht-calendar-footer-content">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info" {{action 'createCalendar'}}>
        <label> Add Calendar</label>
    </button>
</div>
```

I have tried to pass the action from the calendars.hbs to the component with the button, and it runs but what I need to call the method inside calendars.js from the component with the button.

Comment: Have you tried with Ember Service object? https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/applications/services/. You can insert them inside any Ember Object, Component, Controller or Route and it is a way. Also one thing is that your component actions should not have implementation. Instead you need to move action up (this is called Data-down-action-up) and handle inside route or controller

Comment: How to move directly the action implementation to the controller?

Comment: It should be simple. Just do not implement component action instead inform the controller or router to do so. so..instead of your this.calendars.createCalendar(); you would sat this.sendAction('createCalendar...You can read this here: https://dockyard.com/blog/2015/10/14/best-practices-data-down-actions-up. Also you original question asked about sharing controllers code...so again did you tried with Ember.service object to get this abstraction?

Comment: Yes, I'm reading about how to implement my own service to share controllers. What I want to implement is a Use Cases layer to follow Clean Architecture in order to avoid big chains of responsabilities between controller and components

Comment: [Pass the action to the component normally](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/components/triggering-changes-with-actions/) and spare yourself some unnecessary pain!

Answer (score 2):

Use `sendAction('createCalendar',params)` in your component's controller. Your component's controller doesn't know about the controller in your calendar. It is the action up data down principle that Mirza Memic mentioned in your comments. You can handle the action in your route. If you are familiar with sending queries to a database starting from the component level (from component -> route) it is the same principle.

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#method_sendAction

Answer (score 1):

You cannot inject a controller into a component. When you want to do stuff like that, Ember would prefer that you use a Service to communicate between the two entities.

Or, you can just pass the controller down into the component when you instantiate it in the template. It's a cheat, but it's how I prefer to do it.

```
my-component controller=this
```

Also, you can be super ember-y, and utilize sendAction(), and then handle action bubbling in the route.

Pick the way that makes the most sense to you.